# JavaFx Is it possible / how to set CSS selector?

Tags: java, css, javafx, selector

I have a node with multiple children. When I click the node, `requestFocus()` is called, and `node:focused {}` is loaded in my stylesheet.

However, the children don't inherit this focus, and thus `children:focused {}` is not loaded.

I tried looping through and calling `requestFocus()` on each child, but it seems that only one object can be focused at any time, regardless of its location in the hierarchy. (This makes sense - it's just not what I want)

Is there a way around this? Can I set toggle a custom selector and effectively do the same thing?

Comment: You could add a styleclass that is similar to `node:focused` and set it for each child.

Comment: You could use `node:focused children { }`, however then you can't reuse existing `:focused` styles.